# Is the total gravitational energy in the sun greater than the energy that is produced by the sum total of the nuclear fusion contained therein?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, astrophysics, sun, fusion

I think this is off topic, maybe an astronomy question. Unlike a chemical chain reaction or a fission chain reaction I believe fusion cannot sustain inself. Is more energy going out than is going in or is there more gravitatonal energy available than fusion energy going out?

If more energy can be extracted from fusion than goes in to sustain it is that breaking energy conservation? I read Wiki "life cycle of sun" plus of few more other articles but not sure I understand.

Comment: I apologize for such a poor job of framing this question.   All excellent responses by the way.Kudos to all.  I will need time to research each answer individually and I will comment on each. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 4):

To sum up: energy is conserved, fusion converts some mass into energy, this is exothermic, and the gravitational binding energy doesn't contribute much to the heat of the sun.

The total gravitational binding energy of the sun is $\approx 3GM^2/5R\approx 2.3\times 10^{41}$ J. If we divide this with the luminosity of the sun, we get a lifespan of about 20 million years: a star only powered by gravitational binding is not going to shine long (this was an important argument in the 19th century debate about the age of the Earth and solar system, and hinted at new energy sources).

Hydrogen fusion releases about 0.07% of the mass-energy as energy. So if we fuse a solar mass of hydrogen we get $\approx 1.3\times 10^{44}$ J. Which gives a lifetime of $10^{10}$ years. So clearly being fusion powered fits the empirical observations of the sun, the age of the solar system, and other stars really well.

Fusion reactions are exothermic: while there is an activation energy ([about 30 GJ per mol](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/19%3A_Nuclear_Chemistry/19.17%3A_Nuclear_Fusion)) there is much more energy released when it happens (1700 GJ per mol). The high activation energy explains why they don't happen outside stars, the high energy release why stars are so luminious. Still, the energy production density is not high: the sun produces $2\times 10^{-4}$ W per kilogram or 276.5 watts per cubic metre in the core, which famously is about equal to a compost pile.

Comment: The energy output per unit volume is comparable to a compost heap, but comparing per unit mass, the compost heap is the clear winner. :)

Answer (score 1):

Stars sustain fusion for millions or billions of years. The density and temperature in the core of a star is high enough to sustain fusion at a rate that replenishes the outgoing energy. The energy to ignite fusion in a forming star comes from gravity, but once ignited, fusion energy dominates the energy budget of the star.

Comment: An interesting question.  The fusion of the sun will eventually burn out, but the black hole will last forever.  Could this be a simple math problem?

Comment: @foolishmuse the sun will not become a black hole, it doesn't have enough mass to become one, even then black holes don't last forever anyways since they slowly evaporate.

Answer (score 1):

> Unlike a chemical chain reaction or a fission chain reaction I believe fusion cannot sustain inself.

Fusion reactions in the sun proceed very similarly to how regular exothermic chemical reactions proceed.  The reactants are consumed and the products are produced along with a release of energy.

> Is more energy going out than is going in

Depends on the forms of energy you're talking about.  Thermal energy is being produced and goes out.  Otherwise if we consider all forms of energy, they are necessarily in balance.

> is there more gravitatonal energy available than fusion energy going out?

The overall shape and mass of the sun is mostly constant, so gravitational energy isn't really changing.  Some mass leaves the sun, some mass moves closer to the core.  It's not hugely important to the energy balance.

> If more energy can be extracted from fusion than goes in to sustain it is that breaking energy conservation?

No.  In the language of a chemical reaction you could say the hydrogen in the sun has a large amount of potential nuclear energy that is released by converting it into helium.  It is this potential energy that is released during fusion.

Answer (score 1):

I will address the title:

> Is the total gravitational energy in the sun greater than the energy that is produced by the sum total of the nuclear fusion contained therein?

Two concepts are confused in the title.

There is **no** gravitational energy as defined  in the energy and momentum vector of a particle.  It is **potential** energy that the existence of the gravitational attraction between two massive bodies has.

> [Gravitational energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy) or gravitational potential energy is the potential energy a massive object has in relation to another massive object due to gravity. It is the potential energy associated with the gravitational field, which is released (converted into kinetic energy) when the objects fall towards each other. Gravitational potential energy increases when two objects are brought further apart.

The energy that is produced in the sun is the fusion energy at its core and is identified with the mass of the sun, and , given interactions  of the particles composing it, part of the mass can be converted to kinetic energy. All massive objects at rest have an $energy= m_0 c^2$ where  $m_0$ is the [rest mass](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/releng.html) of the object.

The answer by John Doty  illuminates the role of the gravitational potential energy:

> [Star formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_formation) is the process by which dense regions within molecular clouds in interstellar space, sometimes referred to as "stellar nurseries" or "star-forming regions", collapse and form stars

The energy available for fusion in the stars was originally gravitational potential energy that coalesced into the mass of the star, and *is a part* of the four vector that defines the mass of the star.